# What happens when node setTimeout callback becomes null

Tags: node.js, callback

I have a question about callbacks. I have an object which one function is used as a setTimeout callback and that object can be deleted before the callback fires. Will node know not to call it when timeout occurs or will it keep a reference and call it anyway?

Comment: Without a code sample we can only guess. But I'd say it probably will still fire. Removing the reference on the object won't "delete" the function.

Comment: Have you tried writing some demo code for yourself? This seems like something that should be quite simple to do and will probably more useful.

Comment: Yeah, I think some experimentation should clear this up.

Comment: @krojew Once you've done that please post it back here as an answer with whatever else you discover for later travellers who end up here.

Answer (score 0):

Did some tests and it looks like node keeps a reference to the object and fires the callback.

Answer (score -1):

After "delete" the object is not necessarily deleted, you are only deleting your reference of it. The method will still be callable.

```
> cat test.js
var a = {                                                                                                                                                                                          
    method: function() {
        console.log('a' + a.property)   
    },
    property: '1'
}
setTimeout(a.method, 1000);
delete a;

> node test.js                                                                                                                                                                        
a1
```

Comment: That 'delete' isn't doing anything.